# No space with after parenthesis, but needed

Tags: parentheses, chktex

While running `chktex`, I get this error

```
Warning 36 in file.tex line 2062: You should put a space after parenthesis.
pen(s)
```

I am writing the word *pen* but I am adding an *s* in parentheses as an option for a plural form (pens). The final result I want is **pen(s)**.

I just want to make sure there is nothing to worry about in the final build. Or, if there is something to worry about, how do I fix it? I am also NOT in math mode.

The chktex manual says this:

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Ignore the warning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the maintainer of ChkTeX I give you permission to ignore this warning.  :-) Most things in ChkTeX are just that *warnings*.  They aren't errors.  It's meant to warn you of things like "I went to the store(the small one on the corner)" where you forgot to put a space before the parenthesis.

If you find this is never a useful warning for you, then simply turn it off in your `chktexrc` file, or you can turn it off on that single line by adding a comment like

```
pen(s) % chktex 36
```